# persistent microcode update on Linux

Tags: debian, cpu, linux-mint, intel-core-i3

I just tried to update the microcode for my Intel Core i3-3217U processor following the instructions [from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27591/Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-File). I am on Linux Mint Debian edition 2 (3.16.0-5-amd64 kernel).

What I did:

- There is a `/sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload`
- There is no `/lib/firmware/intel-ucode`, only a `/lib/firmware/intel`. I added the folder anyway from the downloaded package.
- As per instruction, as SU I executed

  ```
  echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload
  ```

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep microcode` gives me `0x1f`, which is the updated version - but only as long as the system is running. After a reboot I am back to `0x12`.

How can I make the update permanent?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the Intel microcode update permanent, it must be loaded after each boot. The microcode is stored in volatile RAM in the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can load the microcode to the initial ramdisk leveraging the code from debian package [intel-microcode](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/intel-microcode). This is currently at an older version of the microcodes, but they can be overridden.

After installing the package, I manually removed all files in `/lib/firmware/intel-ucode` and replaced them with the new versions from the Intel download. After that I could update `initrd.img-<kernel version>` with

```
update-initramfs -u
```

`grub-mkconfig` would also execute this.

As I understand it, the `intel-ucode.img` mentioned in the other answer would be a so-called "early initramfs archive". It seems the initramfs-tools hook script that is included in the package chooses for itself whether it places the update module in a separate .img or into the main initrd.img.

**Edit:** It seems the new microcode versions have already landed in the [unstable package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/intel-microcode). Dependencies are unchanged, so they might work on Debian stretch (or jessie, which I am still on.) I suspect it will be only a few days until the new package version will be backported. Then, installing will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

As a intermediate solution while microcode update is not ported into Debian, you may add the "echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload" to /etc/rc.local after you install microcode update per Intel instructions.
This is a rather late patching, but probably OK if you trust your boot environment :)

Answer (score 0):

Microcode updates are applied during boot, and thus should be added to the bootloader, e.g. GRUB2 or systemd-boot. More specifically, **/boot/intel-ucode.img** (or wherever this file is located on your system) should be added as the first initrd image of your boot process (but it should **not** replace your normal initrd image). Once the microcode update package is installed, the grub-mkconfig script usually takes care of this on its own, but you can check if the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file has a similar line:

```
initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux.img
```

If not, you may either reinstall the microcode package, or run the grub-mkconfig script manually.

Comment: The Intel download does not include .img files, but only the raw microcode. It has to be built into a module locally, see my answer.

Comment: The Debian convention does appear to build the microcode as a module into the existing kernel image, but my advice to reinstall the microcode package still stands. From the README file of the intel-microcode package in Debian Stretch:

On a default Debian system (which uses a Debian kernel, the grub
bootloader, and initramfs-tools to create the initramfs for the kernel),
install the "intel-microcode" package and its dependencies, and reboot.

Comment: As I said, the only caveat to this is that currently the microcode versions included in the package are older than the ones published by Intel. There is a post-installation hook to update initrd.img just after package installation. To get the new versions, you have to re-build manually after exchanging the microcode files.

Comment: Oh my, I completely missed the part that you are downloading straight from Intel! I apologize for this. You could try the stretch-backports for a newer version, but it is still likely to be outdated (3.20171117). If you're feeling lucky, you might be able to install the package from Sid (unstable), which has the current version of [3.20180312.1](https://packages.debian.org/sid/intel-microcode) - looking at the dependencies and their versions, it should actually work right out of the box.

Comment: Thx folr the link, I missed that one. Deps are unchanged, so hopefully this comes to backports soon.